# Display date that changes every 15th day of the month

Tags: php

I'm relatively new to php and is currently looking for a way to display a date that adds 1 month on current date and adds 2 months every 15th day of every month.

For example:
Current Date: January 13, 2022
Display Date: February 2022
on January 15, 2022 the date to be displayed is March 2022 (which will be the displayed until February 14, 2022)
on February 15, 2022 the date to be displayed is April 2022

```
<?php
$today = date("D");
$date = date("F Y", strtotime(" +1 months"));
if ($today >= "15") {
    $d=strtotime("+2 Months");
    echo date("F Y", $d);
} else  {
    echo $date; 
}
?>
```

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is almost fine.

data("D") instead of returning 15 will return the day string of the week (mon, wed, etc) so when you compare date("D") with 15 you are comparing "mon" with 15.. (not right). You have to use "d" instead (lowercase d)

This is my version of your same code

```
if (date("d") >= 15) {
    $show_date = date("F Y", strtotime("+2 Month"));
} else {
    $show_date = date("F Y", strtotime("+1 Month"));
}

echo $show_date;
```

Or if you prefer 1 line solution:

```
echo date("F Y", strtotime("+" . (date("d") >= 15 ? 2 : 1) . " Month"));
```